# How would you go about replicating the "Tagging" functionality in TFS discussion board?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, vue.js, frontend

I am looking to replicate the functionality seen on the discussion task board in TFS. I want to if the user types an "@" symbol, it would provide a dropdown of a user list(I have this user list, and it has an id associated with each one). If you selected one, it would add the user to the comment, and when it reaches the server side, it would somehow know to notify the user.

I am using Vue.js, with a .Net back-end. I have no clue where to start with this one. Even the technical term for the functionality I am looking to add would be helpful. Let me know if you require more information.

[image]

Comment: If this is purely for a chat, you could have the recieving chat window look for and detect the string equallying the users name. Or do you ened notificaiton after the fact, if the target user is currently not online too?

Comment: The notification part will all happen in our back end, its not a "Chat" per-se. its more a log of comments, like facebook, where you send them a notification if they were mentioned. Names aren't unique in the system so we need to be aware of that

Comment: If you have to do it in the backend, it is out of my league. However I wonder: Why are names not unique? Usually you can place a "Unique" constraint on any row. And for a username that might be used in a Login form that would even be mandatory.

Comment: I can probably parse any input required from the back end, but have no idea on how to build it on the front end. The username is unique, but the First Name and/or the last name may not be, as we dont enforce it. I am just not sure how to even begin to build whatever I need to so I can have something to parse on the back end.

Comment: You would at least need a Database table to store these Notifications in. I am sure Facebook GUI is just a combination of multiple tables (one for Mentions, one for Answers, etc). All scaled up to the insane amounts of Distributed Computing and Databases you need to run Facebook. Doing indetification with the username alone would be easy. If you need support for carrying the ID, how about writing something like `@[userid=213214]` into the chat, with the local chat interpreting it as the username or Full name of the User rather then displaying the "raw" text?

Comment: I like I like. Follow up part is do you know of any controls that work similar to the one in the screenshot. i.e. provides a dropdown when you type a particular character with all characters that follow the @ symbol being used to search the select control(if that makes sense?)?

Comment: I do understand your question, but it is outside of my knowledge. Web Frontend is not my expertise. I just saw something like what you wanted in a number of MMO Chats (Item and Questlinks in the chat are often realised with such tricks).